# PHP reading a page on my site

Tags: php

I'm trying to open read a page on my own website for a search engine I'm trying to get working.
I've tried several ways of doing it:
**file_get_contents**

```
$temp = file_get_contents("http://www.mysite.com/example01/");
echo $temp;
```

returns:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://www.mysite.com/example01/)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed
>   to open stream: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond. in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\example01\temp.php
>   on line 66

**curl**

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); // Display headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); // Display communication with server       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    print "<pre>\n";
    print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));  // get error info
    echo "\n\ncURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch); // print error info
    echo "\n\ncURL error:" . curl_error($ch); 
    print "</pre>\n";

    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
$temp = curl("http://www.mysite.com/example01/");
echo "'$temp'";
```

returns:

> Array (
>       [url] => http://www.jlwarranty.com/example01/
>       [http_code] => 0
>       [header_size] => 0
>       [request_size] => 0
>       [filetime] => 0
>       [ssl_verify_result] => 0
>       [redirect_count] => 0
>       [total_time] => 0
>       [namelookup_time] => 0
>       [connect_time] => 0
>       [pretransfer_time] => 0
>       [size_upload] => 0
>       [size_download] => 0
>       [speed_download] => 0
>       [speed_upload] => 0
>       [download_content_length] => 0
>       [upload_content_length] => 0
>       [starttransfer_time] => 0
>       [redirect_time] => 0 )
>
> cURL error number:0
>
> cURL error:
>
> ''

it takes about 30 seconds to get the page to reload.

cURL is enabled in php.ini, and so is allow_url_fopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be a firewall issue? I had an issue a while ago for a client where I was unable to use cURL or the http stream wrapper to access an external resource, despite both being enabled. I was told by the hosting support that their firewall barred outbound http requests from their servers by default and they would need to add an exception for the site I was trying to access.

From the first error message it looks as if you're running this on your own PC using IIS. Is there something in the IIS config or your computers setup that is stopping the server accessing remote resources?

Comment: That was the problem. I got around it by putting our sites IP address into the hosts file as www.mysite.com, so that the search script doesn't have to be altered drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Is your site hosted with a hosting provider?

Sometimes a hosted site isn't visible to itself under its usual name - it might be called **www.mysite.com** from the outside, but you have to call it something like **www.mysite.com.internal.myprovider.com** to access it from within the hosting provider's network.

It's worth asking your hosting provider's support department whether this is the case, and what your site's internal name is.

Comment: Its hosted on Rackspace... I'll have to give them a call.

Comment: Also, its a windows machine running IIS, so I don't know if that makes a difference.